# Remove duplicate Maximum and Minimum from unsorted array

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I currently have a handful of arrays containing the following values

```
var array = new[] { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 9};
```

I need to remove duplicates of the minimum and maximum, so in this case the final product would be

```
var array = new[] { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 4};
```

Comment: You should starting by sort your array

Comment: Not if he needs that array would be in same order.

Comment: if min and max are the same value should the result array just be a one element array? or two iff there are more than two elements in the original?

Comment: @IssakMadden you should accep a answer that fits your needs

Answer (score 5):

```
    var ar = new[] { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 9 };
    var max = ar.Max();
    var min = ar.Min();
    var bmin = 0;
    var bmax = 0;
    var res = ar.Where(i => (i > min || 0 == bmin++) && (i < max || 0 == bmax++));
```

Comment: works on my PC.. seems dontnetfildle doesnt do postincrement right

Comment: +1 seems to work fine when you iterate over a foreach loop, see : https://dotnetfiddle.net/DfbjH3, cool use of bool eval short circuiting

Comment: Marco Bong, by C# rules, ++ works after ==, and the right side of || is not evaluated if the left side is true. so bmin is increased only after a min value is met, and the first min is taken as by that time bmin is still 0. same with bmax.

Comment: thanks, just cant imagine how it actually work in Where(i=>) clause, maybe one day i will understand when i meet similar question. : )

Answer (score 2):

**If performance isn't a concern** then something like this would work

```
var min = arr.Min();
var max = arr.Max();

bool foundMin = false, foundMax = false;
var result = arr
               .Where(a=>!((a==min && foundMin) || (a==max &&foundMax)))
               .Select(a=>{ 
                    if(a==min) 
                    {
                       foundMin = true;
                    }
                    else if(a==max) 
                    {
                      foundMax = true;
                    }

                    return a;
            }).ToArray();
```

I can't think of a way to do this with less than two passes, so really the only improvement I could see would make a loop to find both min and max at the same time

```
int min,max;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(i==0) min = max = arr[i];
    else if(arr[i]<min) 
    {
        min = arr[i];
    } 
    else if (arr[i]>max)
    {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

**but if you don't care about performance would just use the built in linq method** just because it is less code, but again only if performance isn't a concern

**And as a regular loop**

```
//assuming calculated min & max with loop or .Min & .Max linq extensions
var newLs = new List<int>();
int[] result;
bool foundMin = false, foundMax = false;
foreach(var val in arr)
{
    if(val == min)
    {
        if(foundMin) continue;
        foundMin = true;
    }
    if(val == max)
    {
       if(foundMax) continue;
       foundMax = true;
    }

    newLs.Add(val);
}

result = newLs.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

---------------------Edited-----------------------------

```
////Correct        
        Int32[] arr = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 9 };
        List<Int32> newArr = new List<Int32>();
        Int32 max = arr.Max();
        Int32 min = arr.Min();
        Boolean removeMax = false;
        Boolean removeMin = false;

        foreach (var each in arr)
        {                
            if (each == min || each == max)
            {
                if (!removeMax || !removeMin)
                {
                    if (each == min)
                    {
                        newArr.Add(each);
                        removeMin = true;
                    }

                    if (each == max)
                    {
                        newArr.Add(each);
                        removeMax = true;
                    }                        
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newArr.Add(each);
            }               
        }
        var arrAfter = newArr.ToArray();
```

Comment: Only max and min values needs to be removed. Not All duplicates.

Comment: interesting, keep try-ing

Comment: Hope to see better solution, i know this is not perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

This will need to iterate though `array` only twice.

```
 var max = int.MinValue;
 var min = int.MaxValue;
 var array = new [] { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 9 };
 // Get min and max values. With just one iteration.
 foreach (var element in array)
     {
     if (element < min)
         {
         min = element;
         }
     if (max < element)
         {
         max = element;
         }
     }

 var minCount = 0;
 var maxCount = 0;
 var list = array.ToList ();
 // Search for duplicates with second iteration.
 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
     {
     if (list[i] == min)
         {
         if (minCount++ != 0)
             {
             list.RemoveAt (i--);
             }
         continue;
         }
     if (list[i] == max)
         {
         if (maxCount++ != 0)
             {
             list.RemoveAt (i--);
             }
         }
     }
 array = list.ToArray ();
```